# Событие on click срабатывает на третий клик

Tags: javascript

Всё остальное работает, подскажите, в чём может быть дело?

```
<script>
            var flag=true;
            $('.menu-message').click(function(){
               if (flag==true){
              $('.menu-message').click(clickPrev);  

            function clickPrev(){
              $('.hoverl_6R').trigger('click');
            };
                flag=false;
            }
            else {
            $('.menu-message').click(clickPrev);

            function clickPrev(){
                  $('.closeButton_3Y').trigger('click');
                };
            flag=true;
            }
            });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var flag = true;
$('.menu-message').click(function() {
  flag ? clickPrev_True() : clickPrev_False();
  flag = !flag;

  function clickPrev_True() {
    $('.hoverl_6R').trigger('click');
  }
  function clickPrev_False() {
    $('.closeButton_3Y').trigger('click');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо, Ваш код работает. 
А в чем дело в моём?

Comment: @KovalenkoVadim Пожалуйста. Неправильно в Вашем коде то, что Вы назначаете обработчики событий внутри других обработчиков событий. Таким образом, количество обработчиков все время растет. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: @Igor, гениально, а я думал, что этот код должен делать, а тут всего то!!!

Comment: @Leonid Да, трудно понять, что там делается. Особенно из-за отступов.